# NullPointerException when accessing a Fragment's textView in an Activity

Tags: java, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

It seems to be a common problem, but after hours of trying random solutions provided as answers to similar questions, my code still produces a NullPointerException when I access a Fragment's textView from an Activity.

I can include (and view) my Fragment when its textView has a predefined Text or by using `setText()` in `onCreateView()` of the Fragment class but not by using a setter method (here `set_message_success()`).

This is my Fragment class `Fragment_Message`:

```
public class Fragment_Message extends Fragment {

    TextView textview_message;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messagebox, container, false);
        textview_message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_textview_message);
        textview_message.setText("test");
        return view;
    }

    public void set_message_success(String text) {
        textview_message.setText(text);
    }
}
```

And the relevant lines from the Activity class:

```
FragmentManager frag_manager    = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = frag_manager.beginTransaction();
Fragment_Message fragment       = new Fragment_Message();
fragment.set_message_success(message_green);
transaction.add(R.id.home_fragment_container, fragment, "Fragment");
transaction.commit();
```

`home_fragment_container` is a RelativeLayout in my main_activity.xml, `fragment_textview_message` is the textView in the fragment_messagebox.xml, just to let you know, what these are.

The NullPointerException is caused in `set_message_success()`. Any Ideas?

Comment: `textview_message` is set to `null` perhaps? Does `R.id.fragment_textview_message` exists?

Comment: @toddlermenot Yes, `fragment_textview_message` is the id of a textView in the fragment_messagebox.xml.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a fragment but the creation cycle is not executed.
This line :

```
Fragment_Message fragment = new Fragment_Message();
```

does NOT automatically calls `onCreateView`, thus your text view is not initialized (is `null`) and when you try to set its text with the following line:

```
fragment.set_message_success(message_green);
```

you get the exception since the text view member is not initialized so either initialize the text view in a constructor or define the fragment in the desired layout.

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) for a detailed information

Comment: I tested a constructor with a single line `this.textview_message = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_textview_message);`. But this also produces a NullPointerException. I already checked the android website today but either they include a fragment via xml or they discuss a way more complicated problem than just using a setText() method. Both examples are not really usable for me...

Comment: You said why there is an error, but not how to fix it. What is the fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem apparently is the lifecycle of the fragment. When I add a fragment (done in the activity's `onCreate()`) and define it's textView-text in the fragment's `onCreateView()`, the fragment will be displayed without problems. But accessing the fragment's textView in the activity's `onCreate()` fails, because - I guess - the fragment is not attached yet.

So I **added** the fragment in the activity's `onCreate()` and **changed** the fragment's textView-text in the activity's `onResume()`, where (as I understand it) the fragment should be attached. Furthermore, it helps to use `executePendingTransactions()`. My now working code:

Home.java

```
FragmentManager     frag_manager;
FragmentTransaction transaction;
Fragment_Message    fragment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    frag_manager    = getFragmentManager();
    transaction     = frag_manager.beginTransaction();
    fragment        = new Fragment_Message();

    transaction.add(R.id.home_fragment_container, fragment, "Fragment_Messagebox");
    transaction.commit();
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
        frag_manager.executePendingTransactions();          
        fragment.set_message_success("a message");
}
```

Fragment_Message.java

```
public class Fragment_Message extends Fragment {

    TextView textview_message;
    View view;

    public Fragment_Message() {}


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messagebox, container, false);
        return view;
    }


    public void set_message_success(String text) {
        textview_message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_textview_message);
        textview_message.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this solve the problem? I think I have the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907625/why-is-accessing-textview-of-a-fragment-inside-activity-throwing-an-error